# как вставить картинку вместо белой линии c#

Tags: c#, winforms, анимация, разработка-игр, графика

хотел бы узнать как вместо белой линии, рисующейся от шара(ПАНЕЛИ)к курсору мыши, вставить рисунок, чтобы он так же располагался от шара к направлению мыши.
Снизу привел код:

```
if (_mouseDowm)
            {
                
                Point ball = new Point((int)_whiteBall.position.X (int)_whiteBall.position.Y);

                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White, 5f);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, ball, _mouseLocation);
                pen.Dispose();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [TextureBrush](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.texturebrush?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).
[How to: Draw a Line Filled with a Texture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-a-line-filled-with-a-texture?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

```
Point ball   = new Point(10, 10);
Point mouse = new Point(500, 500);

using var brush = new TextureBrush(bitmap);
using var pen = new Pen(brush, 50f);

e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, ball, mouse);
```

`bitmap` - ваше изображение. Его загрузите заранее, скажем, в событии `Load`. Не нужно это делать при каждом движении мыши.